# Session could not be loaded

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My website worked all the day.
Now at the end of night the website crashed and i got this error on my console:

[image]

Can someone help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check connections with session manager (mongodb, redis, ...)

delete all sessions and restart